# AirPort Express no power-on - can it be repaired or replaced?

Tags: airport

I have a first-generation Airport Express that has the common failure of simply not powering on. There are [several](http://www.ifixit.com/blog/blog/2010/10/06/how-to-fix-your-airport-express-base-station/) [sites](http://uavbob.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/airport-express-power-supply-repair/) showing how to [open](http://www.vonwentzel.net/ABS/Dissection-Express/index.html) or [repair](http://echoone.com/airport-express/) the device, but all basically involve destroying the exterior and/or keeping it in two (exposed) parts afterwards.

Is there any way to get this fixed without destroying it? I have no Apple Care - do Apple consider doing repairs (for less than the cost of a new one)? It seems like a waste to chuck it and buy a new one. Or perhaps it is announced as a manufacturing defect? I couldn't find anything like that. Any chance of a friendly Apple Store employee getting a replacement, at least saving the full cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that the Airport Express is considered a serviceable product. As you have seen from the repair sites it isn't easily opened. A repair from Apple isn't likely to be available or cost effective. It never hurts to ask though -- especially at the Genius Bar where they have some discretion depending on your situation.

Without destroying the exterior, you are likely faced with getting a replacement. You could save some money by buying a [refurbished Airport Express](http://store.apple.com/us/product/FB321LL/A) from Apple. And perhaps even sell your old one for [parts on eBay](http://shop.ebay.com/i.html?_nkw=airport+express+broken) in case someone else wants to split it open.